# Hide parent tr when all children li have same class

Tags: jquery, html-table, hide

I am listing results for a sporting event.  Each event has it's own row in a table, some with multiple results, listed as li items.  People need to be able to filter the results, so by using checkboxes, they can eliminate results from the list.  I do this by adding the class .gone to those results, which makes them display:none.  However, if they filter the results enough, some events no longer have any visible results.  If that becomes the case, I want that complete row in the table to be display:none.

Basically, if all li within a tr have the class .gone, the parent tr should also be assigned the class of .gone.

I'm a bit of a noob on this and I've tried so many different example on this site, but I'm clearly missing something.

Here is the HTML:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td valign="top" width="75px"><div id="tableHeader">Date</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><div id="tableHeader">Event</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><div id="tableHeader">Location</div></td>
</tr>

<tr id="section">

    <td valign="top">
        <div id="postmeta">3/2/2013</div>
    </td>

    <td valign="top">
        <div class="posttitle" id="post-103">AT&#038;T American Cup</div>
            <ul>
            <li class="Men"><a href="http://usagym.org/PDFs/Results/m_13ac_final.pdf" target="_new">Men's All-Around</a></li>
            <li class="Women"><a href="http://usagym.org/PDFs/Results/w_13ac_final.pdf" target="_new">Women's All-Around</a></li>
            </ul>
    </td>

    <td valign="top">Worcester, Mass.</td>

</tr>


<tr id="section">

    <td valign="top">
        <div id="postmeta">3/1/2013</div>
    </td>

    <td valign="top">
        <div class="posttitle" id="post-106">Nastia Liukin Cup</div>
            <ul>
            <li class="Women"><a href="http://usagym.org/PDFs/Results/w_13nlc_final.pdf" target="_new">Final Results</a></li>
            </ul>
    </td>

    <td valign="top">Worcester, Mass.</td>

</tr>
```

So then, what have I tried?  Many things, but this was my last attempt:

```
if ($("#section ul li.gone").length == $("#section ul li").length) {
// all list items are selected
$('tr').addClass('gone');}
```

I also apologize for this code.  This is my first post here and I've tried to rangle the code formatting.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is the page I'm working on... if it helps at all:  http://dev-public.usagym.org/2013/?cat=7

UPDATE:  As one responder pointed out, I could check to see if the event's li are hidden, and if so, hide the event title.  However, I initally want to hide the ul until someone clicks on the event title.  I did not have that code on the page, but I do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea in comparing the lengths of the sets.

Loop through each `tr` and apply the comparisons separately:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $lis = $this.find('li');

    if ($lis.length === 0) return;

    if ($lis.filter('.gone').length === $lis.length) {
        $this.addClass('gone');
    } else {
        $this.removeClass('gone');
    }
});
```

I've also made the loop skip the check if it doesn't have any `li` children, since it will also loop through your header row.

Comment: Tried it... nothing.  I just added the link to the page I'm working on so that people can see what I'm working with.

Comment: Your page doesn't add the `gone` class to the `li`s

Comment: When I check in on firebug, it does.  Unclicking any checkbox at the top adds 'gone' to that particular class.  For example, any div with the class of women get gone added to it when the Women checkbox is unchecked.  That's what makes it disappear.

Comment: Ah, I was testing with the Group checkbox. I see that it does it for Women and Men. It works when I run my code after unchecking Men and Women. Are you making this code execute every time a checkbox is changed, and after the class is added?

Comment: Ummmm... sad to say to don't know how to do that.

Comment: You have a `script` tag that contains the `click` handlers, e.g. `$('.toggleMen').click`, etc. Add my code to each of those, after the line where you toggle the class. Of course, a better practise is to make those dynamic so you don't have to write a specific handler for each button, but that's not really in the scope of this question.

Comment: Ok... did some research there and I got it to work, thanks to you.  However, now I need to remove that same `gone` class once the checkbox is clicked again to make it reappear.  Do you have any idea how you would alter your code to account for that?  Some toggle?